# How can we use an operator in that class?

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

I want to write a function in class, using the operator that I've defined it later before in that class.But I don't know how to show the operator that now you must use the values of YOUR (x,y).
(I saw someone used `$this->func_name` in php. but here I don't know.

```
class Point
{
  public:

    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator==(Point p)
    {
        if (x == p.x && y == p.y)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    bool searchArea(vector <Point> v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            if (v[i] == /* what ?? */  )
                return 1;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //...
.
.
. 
    if (p.searchArea(v))
       //...
}
```

Comment: `bool operator==(Point p) const`

Comment: Also the vector should be passed by `const vector<Point>&`, searchArea should be a const function as well, and should return `true` and `false`.

Comment: Better yet: `bool operator==(const Point &p) const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen two ways:

```
 if ( *this == v[i] )
 if ( operator==(v[i]) )
```

`this` is a pointer to the current object.  `*this` is a *reference* to the current object.  Since the comparison operator takes a reference, you have to dereference the `this` pointer.  Or you can just call the member function directly, which passes `this` implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Where you have `/* what ?? */` you want `*this`

Comment: thanks! but why a pointer to this?  I mean why *this instead of this?

Comment: that is not a pointer to `this`, but instead is dereferencing the `this` pointer to access the object `this` is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in C++ is a pointer to the current object. If you want to access to actual object you need to add de-referencing operator `*` (different from Java). For example: `(*this).x`

```
class Point
{
  public:

    int x;
    int y;


    bool operator==(Point p)
    {
        if (x == p.x && y == p.y)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    bool searchArea(vector <Point> v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            if (v[i] == *this  )
                return 1;
        return 0;
    }
};
```